# Dúvida em questão de listas e repetições ! (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, eu estou com dúvida em uma questão de uma lista de Algoritimos, ela pede para criar um algoritimo onde o usuário informa uma certa quantidade de números e para quando ele digitar 0. Ao final do programa ele quer que o Algoritimo separe os números pares dos impares.

O meu problema em sí é que o meu programa não está informando o primeiro número dígitado pelo usuário e eu não sei como solucionar Abaixo coloquei uma foto para tornar facil a visualização do problema. Também aceito dicas e críticas, sou novo em programação.

```py
x = int(input("Digite valores"))

lista = []
lista2 = []
lista3 = []

while x != 0:
    x = int(input("Digite valores"))
    lista.append(x)

for i in range(len(lista)):
    if i%2 != 0:
        lista2.append(lista[i])
print("Os valores ímpares são",lista2)

for s in range(len(lista)):
    if s%2 == 0:
        lista3.append(lista[s])
print("Os valores pares são",lista3)
```

<sup>[screenshot do código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACOqZ.png)</sup>

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta para remover o código como image. Conforme você pode ler [nesta postagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485), códigos em formato de imagem não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: A foto não facilita a visualização, pelo contrário dificulta e impede quem quiser testar o seu código que o copie e cole no depurador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo, pois o primeiro elemento (meio que propositalmente) não é colocado na lista. Sugiro que tire a primeira linha do código, troque `while != 0` por um looping "infito": `while True:` e coloque uma condição dentro do looping, para que se o número digitado pelo usuário for 0 o programa saia do looping.

Comment: Refiz o programa com as dicas e deu super certo ! Muito obrigado Alex !

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro valor digitado não é adicionado na lista porque você não o adicionou na lista antes de entrar no while e fazer a leitura novamente. Para que todos os valores sejam lidos e adicionados na lista você deve fazer a leitura somente dentro do while.

Fiz uma verificação para não adicionar o zero na lista também:

```
<!-- language: python -->
lista = []
lista2 = []
lista3 = []
x = None # Inicia um valor qualquer para que a condição do while seja verdadeira

while x != 0:
    # Toda leitura do x que for feita será armazenada na lista
    x = int(input("Digite valores: "))
    if x != 0:
        lista.append(x)

for i in range(len(lista)):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        lista2.append(lista[i])
print("Os valores ímpares são: ", lista2)

for s in range(len(lista)):
    if s % 2 == 0:
        lista3.append(lista[s])
print("Os valores pares são: ", lista3)
```

Resutado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]